# Working Twitter Feeds on Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: development, social

been trying to get a Twitter feed to work in SharePoint 2013 for some time but it just doesn't seem to be playing ball.

I've tried a couple of methods (embedding the code straight in and also using the content editor using the code in a text file).

Both of these have got me about 99% there in that when I input the code or link it to the correct text file with the code in it shows the Twitter feed all nice and dandy, but then when I come to save the page it disappears and just leaves me with the text "Tweets by..." at the bottom and I can't figure out why.

Then if I go back into the edit the page it reappears.

I'm using the code from the Twitter Widgets section of their site.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. I know its not the code because I am using the exact same code in my SharePoint 2010 environment and it works. And like the above poster stated, in 2013 it looks like it works when editing the page, but when I click save I am left with the same text "Tweets by..." My guess is there is an issue calling the javascript catalog from twitter. That part of the code looks as follows: <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platfor

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the very same issue with SharePoint 2013, and I believe I have found the culprit. **Short answer** - go to your site features and disable the Minimal Download Strategy feature.

Details:
SharePoint 2013 has implemented something called the Minimal Download Strategy (MDS). At a high level, this new feature (yes its a SharePoint feature that you can disable) basically pulls the delta (change) from the original page you loaded and the page you are navigating to, and by doing so it only has to render the delta, which makes the rendering much quicker ( [here](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013---introduction-to-the-minimal-download-strategy-mds) is a detailed article on MDS.)

But! this uses a slightly different URL than what we are expecting. If I am in my portal (http://testportal.com) and I want to navigate to my Library (lets call it Library) by clicking on the Left Hand navigation we get a different URL than one would expect. Typically in the past the URL would be: http://testportal.com/Library , but when using MDS the actual URL is: http://testportal.com/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Library . This new feature of SharePoint is pretty cool, as long as its not interfering with any of your content (like the Twitter issue posted here).

Now the reason this inst an issue when you edit a page is that SharePoint doesn't use MDS for paage editing, but once you finish editing, you will notice your URL has the _layouts/15/start.aspx# in it. If you remove that portion your Twitter feed should load perfectly.

So this solution has its takeoff's. If you want your site to use the newest SharePoint functionality and have the best performance, do not disable this feature. But if you want your Twitter widget to function properly 100% of the time, your going to have to disable this feature.

Comment: Don't forget to format your code, please.

Comment: Also, this is not an answer. Please change it to a comment and consider leaving the code as a jsfiddle link in the comment.

Comment: Changing to comment

Comment: @John0834 I have re-opened post and manually applied your edits for you. Please don't edit the original question!

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that enables you to keep the general performance benefits of MDS in SharePoint 2013 whilst allowing your twitter/facebook feeds to render...host the feeds in html files on another web server. (You could create the site in IIS Manager on your front-end server for example, outside of the wss folder)

Then I just put  tags around my widget code, store them away on whichever website I choose, and then use the Page Viewer webpart in SharePoint to render them.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked a simple answer from "Book Bellle" [here](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.ca/2012/12/add-twitter-widget-to-sharepoint-using.html).

change the `<script>` tag to `<script type="text/javascript">`